# Avro: convert UNION schema to RECORD schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro, parquet

I have auto-generated Avro schema for simple class hierarchy:

```
trait T {def name: String}
case class A(name: String, value: Int) extends T
case class B(name: String, history: Array[String]) extends T
```

It looks like this:

```
 [{
  "name": "org.example.schema.raw.A",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [{
    "name": "name",
    "type": "string"
  }, {
    "name": "value",
    "type": "int"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "org.example.schema.raw.B",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [{
    "name": "name",
    "type": "string"
  }, {
    "name": "history",
    "type": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": "string"
    }
  }]
}]
```

This schema works well for reading data from JSON into `GenericRecord` using plain Avro API. Next thing I try to achieve is storing all such `GenericRecord` objects into single parquet file using `AvroParquetWriter`:

```
val writer = new AvroParquetWriter[GenericRecord](file, schema)
writer.write(record)
writer.close()
```

This code fails at the first line with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Avro schema must be a record.
at parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convert(AvroSchemaConverter.java:96)
at parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.writeSupport(AvroParquetWriter.java:137)
at parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:54)
at parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:86)
```

No wonder, [AvroSchemaConverter](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-avro/src/main/java/parquet/avro/AvroSchemaConverter.java#L72) contains following lines:

```
if (!avroSchema.getType().equals(Schema.Type.RECORD)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Avro schema must be a record.");
}
```

And my schema type is UNION. Any ideas/help in mapping (merging) this UNION schema into RECORD schema or any other suggestions are extremely appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

1) Read JSON from input using union scheme into `GenericRecord`
2) Get or create `AvroParquetWriter` for type:

```
val writer = writers.getOrElseUpdate(record.getType, new AvroParquetWriter[GenericRecord](getPath(record.getType), record.getShema)
```

3) Write record into file:

```
writer.write(record)
```

4) Close all writers when all data are consumed from input:

```
writers.values.foreach(_.close())
```

5) Load data from directory into Spark SQL DataFrame:

```
sqlContext.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("/tmp/data/")
```

6) Data can be processed or stored as is - it's already merged by Spark:

```
df.write.format("parquet").save("merged.parquet")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question about merging : you could use the following `case class Merged(name: String, value: Option[Int], history: Option[Array[String]])` and use the generated schema of that to write your data. 
In general, if you have a schema forward compatible for both A and B, it will write both correctly.

Or, since, as you said, avro won't let you write all your data in the same file, maybe you can split the output by type, and write one file per type ? I know I'd probably do that in most use cases I can think of, but maybe it's not applicable for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding options you've described: 1) yes I can, but in real life we have a big hierarchy (>100 case classes extending 5-6 base traits) and even have custom code generator that flattens and make unions for sub-hierarchies, but it code is pretty ad-hoc and hard to support  2) it is an option too, write file per concrete class and then merge it; anyway I need to load it into single Spark table at the end, but I'm not sure how good Spark will handle it

Comment: AvroParquetReader has two generic arguments : one for read class, and one for projection class. I don't have a good syntax example handy (and iirc, it's a bit annoying to find :D), but basically you can do read[B, T] to read a file writen with B schema and still have a RDD[T]. Which would make option 2 doable I suppose.

Comment: It's even simpler then I thought: write file per concrete class, then use Spark SQL to load all such file into DataFrame. Spark SQL merges schemes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your trait with a case class which is a Record.

case class Reord[K](key: K, value: T)